# Where should I install Composer?

Tags: composer-php

Just wondering where I should install Composer. It kind of wrecked my environment last time. I'm running XAMPP and i'm looking to use it within some Framework sites. So to me the XAMPP folder itself seems appropriate. Would that be correct? The main thing for me is that it doesn't alter any environment paths or the such.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: I just don't understand how `composer` can wreck your environment, anyways, I think installing it globally is better and it doesn't matter where you install (globally) it but to use it like `composer command` you have to keep the path listed in your environment path variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main aspect is that you'd probably want to run Composer easily in the command shell. This implies that Composer has to be in any directory mentioned in the path variable.

Have a look at your current path, pick a convenient directory, and put the `composer.phar` file there.

If you don't like that, you could also create a batch file that does run PHP with that phar file in a different location, and passes all the other command line arguments to it.